# ZXing(Zebra Xing) Unable to scan/ detect the barcode in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, zxing, barcode-scanner

I posted couple other questions in regards to Zxing please **DONT** mark it duplicate just because they are about Zxing..

So, in my Xamarin iOS app, I am using Zxing to detect the barcode. I am using https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/tree/master/Samples/iOS as example.

I am using a subview to scan for barcodes. The custom overlay n everything works fine but it is unable to detect the barcode when I'm trying to scan.
Can anyone please help me out where I'm doing wrong or missing something.

**CODE**

```
public UIView camView;

        AVCaptureScannerView scannerView;
        UIActivityIndicatorView loadingView;
        UIView loadingBg;
        UIView topBg;
        UIView bottomBg;
        MobileBarcodeScanner scanner;
        public event Action<ZXing.Result> OnScannedResult;
        public MobileBarcodeScanningOptions ScanningOptions { get; set; }

public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            camView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, this.View.Frame.Width, this.View.Frame.Height / 3)) { BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear };
            scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();

            Root = new RootElement("ZXingDwatNet.Mobile") {
                new Section {


                    camView
                }
            };

            scannerView = new AVCaptureScannerView(camView.Frame);

            camView = scannerView;

            loadingBg = camView;// new UIView(this.View.Frame) { BackgroundColor = UIColor.Purple, AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleDimensions };
            loadingView = new UIActivityIndicatorView(UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.White)
            {
                AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleMargins
            };
            loadingView.Frame = new CGRect((this.View.Frame.Width - loadingView.Frame.Width) / 4,
                (this.View.Frame.Height - loadingView.Frame.Height) / 4,
                loadingView.Frame.Width / 4,
                loadingView.Frame.Height / 4);

            loadingBg.AddSubview(loadingView);
            View.AddSubview(loadingBg);
            loadingView.StartAnimating();

            this.View.InsertSubviewBelow(scannerView, loadingView);

            this.View.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;


        }

        void HandleScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
        {
            string msg = "";

            if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Text))
                msg = "Found Barcode: " + result.Text;
            else
                msg = "Scanning Canceled!";

            this.InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                var av = new UIAlertView("Barcode Result", msg, null, "OK", null);
                av.Show();
            });
        }

        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            //scannerView.OnScannerSetupComplete += HandleOnScannerSetupComplete;
            //camView = scannerView;
            var options = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
            {
                AutoRotate = false,
                UseFrontCameraIfAvailable = false,
                TryHarder = true
            };
            ScanningOptions = options;

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(7, 0))
            {
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.Default;
                SetNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate();
            }
            else
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.BlackTranslucent, false);

            Console.WriteLine("Starting to scan...");

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
           {
               BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => scannerView.StartScanning(result =>
               {

                       //if (!ContinuousScanning)
                       //{
                       // Console.WriteLine("Stopping scan...");
                       // scannerView.StopScanning();
                       //}

                       var evt = this.OnScannedResult;
                   if (evt != null)
                       evt(result);

               }, this.ScanningOptions));
           });
        }

        void HandleOnScannerSetupComplete()
        {
            BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
           {
               if (loadingView != null && loadingBg != null && loadingView.IsAnimating)
               {
                   loadingView.StopAnimating();

                   UIView.BeginAnimations("zoomout");

                   UIView.SetAnimationDuration(2.0f);
                   UIView.SetAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseOut);

                   loadingBg.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(2.0f, 2.0f);
                   loadingBg.Alpha = 0.0f;

                   UIView.CommitAnimations();


                   loadingBg.RemoveFromSuperview();
               }
           });
        }
```

Comment: it will fire OnScannedResult when it detects a barcode, but you have not assigned a handler for that event so it does nothing.

Comment: Thanks. Works now..

Comment: Hey Jason, posted similar question but for android, can you please advise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034381/how-to-make-zebra-xing-zxing-as-subview-in-xamarin-android