# How to make Zebra Xing (Zxing) as subview in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, zxing, barcode-scanner

In my Xamarin.Android app, I want to use ZXing to scan barcode. I want to display the scanner in the view of an activity.

**Code:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="5">
    <Button
        android:text="Scan with Default Overlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonScanDefaultView"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scanView"
        android:layout_weight="2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```csharp
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);
    scannerFragment = new ZXingScannerFragment ();
    scannerFragment.CustomOverlayView = CustomOverlayView;
    scannerFragment.UseCustomOverlayView = UseCustomOverlayView;
    scannerFragment.TopText = TopText;
    scannerFragment.BottomText = BottomText;
    this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ()
                .Replace (Resource.Id.scanView, scannerFragment, "ZXINGFRAGMENT")
                .Commit ();
}
```

I'm getting an error stating that I cannot convert support.v4.fragment into android.app.Fragment.

Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong and how should I approach this to get the scanner view (of ZXing) in a layout of my current activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ZXingScannerFragment` derives from `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` while the `Activity.FragmentManager` expects fragments derived from `Android.App.Fragment`.

Now, how to fix that:

1. Inherit your activity from any activity that works with Android.Support.V4. Easiest would to use `Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity` from package `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` that is already installed by `ZXing.Net.Mobile` package as a dependency.
2. When you have correct activity, you can use `this.SupportFragmentManager` instead of `this.FragmentManager` to work with Support.V4-based fragments.

So, layout you have is good. Code should be updated to something like:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using ZXing.Mobile;
using Android.Support.V4.App;

namespace ZXingSample
{
    [Activity(Label = "ZXing Sample", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : FragmentActivity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            var scannerFragment = new ZXingScannerFragment();
            scannerFragment.UseCustomOverlayView = false;
            scannerFragment.TopText = "Scan your code";
            scannerFragment.BottomText = "Then proceed";
            this.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                        .Replace(Resource.Id.scanView, scannerFragment, "ZXINGFRAGMENT")
                        .Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Launching the app, you will see your scanner:

[image: sample app]

Comment: Its working now, but is it possible to call v4.fragment that app. fragment ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, all you need is use fragment without any options like custom overlay, top/bottom texts.

Comment: Its working now Alex, one other question, is it possible to call v4.fragment from app. fragment ?

Comment: Check this answer, @TheDeveloper http://stackoverflow.com/a/6672688/883738

Comment: Its taking about fragments within fragments, but my issues is support.v4.fragment within app.fragment which cannot be solved with their suggestions

Comment: @TheDeveloper here is the thing, ff you want to make your app use fragments, and want to target devices before API 11, you must use android.support.v4.app.Fragment. However, if you're only targeting devices running API 11 or above, you can use android.app.Fragment.

Comment: thank you for the input, I'm forced t use support.v4.fragment as its a third party api. one more question, now I am getting the custom overlay n all which you shared in the screenshot but the background is black even on the device. I'm not able to scan anything it totally black just as displayed on your screenshot. any advice on that?

Comment: @TheDeveloper check camera permissions and read ZXing getting started carefully. My guess it is camera permissions missing.